# Pros and Cons: Catching database errors vs. Validating user input

Tags: database

I have an application with a database that has a lot of foreign keys.

A lot of the data being inserted comes from users.

I was just wondering is: Is it better to run validation on user input before inserts or insert and just write error catching code?

Are there performance/stylistic/security benefits to either?

The knee jerk response to me seems to be do both, but doing validation before seems a safer option if only one of the two was done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a brilliant question - and in my view, one of the benefits of the use of an object relational mapper.

In general, the relational tools your database provides are all about protecting data validity - "customer" must have an "account manager" relationship, "user_name" may not be null, "user_id" must be unique etc.

Those tools are necessary, but not sufficient, to validate the data users input into the database.

Your front-end/middle tier code has its own rules - which are usually not expressed in relational terms; in most modern development languages, they're about objects and the relationships between the objects, or their attributes - for instance, a phone number must contain numbers, a name must start with a capital letter.

I'm assuming your users don't interact with the database through SQL - that you've built some kind of user interface which allows them to look up associations (and thus populate the foreign key).

In this case, my preferred architecture is:

- Validate as early as you can - in JavaScript for web apps, or in the GUI code for desktop apps. This reduces the number of round trips, and thus creates a more responsive user experience.
- Have each layer implement validation for its key domain logic - your classes should validate their expectations, your database should validate the foreign keys and nullability.
- Don't depend on "higher" levels to validate - you can't predict how your code is going to be used in the future; a class you've written for one application may get re-used by another.
- Work out a way to keep the validation rules in sync across the layers - either through technology or process.

Comment: +1 : Don't depend on "higher" levels to validate - you can't predict how your code is going to be used in the future; a class you've written for one application may get re-used by another.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it should be a question of which.  I always do both, as you suggested.  As far as pros and cons, I will say that I think it is easier to find user input problems and handle them in a user friendly manner earlier in the life cycle, as opposed to waiting until the database throws back an error.  However, if your validation does not catch everything or if there is a database error unrelated to user input, it is still important to catch the error at some point.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you'll need to trap errors. Who knows what will happen? SQL timeout? No amount of data validation will help on those kind of problems.

Like most problems, they are cheapest to catch early; don't let users enter invalid data/validate data before sending it to a server. Not business logic per se, but that dates don't contain alpha characters, etc.

In a mid-tier, I would still validate inputs. Another developer may call your business logic without vetting the inputs. I prefer my business logic in this area because it is easier to write and debug than creating logic in stored procedures.

On the database, I prefer constraints when rules are absolutes such as you can't have an internal user without a user id; the reason is to prevent other developers from writing scripts that would do things that should not be allowed.